# closing pydeequ callback server

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-deequ, pydeequ

I'm using pydeequ with Spark 3.0.1 to perform some constraint checks on data.

As for testing with the `VerificationSuite`, after calling `VerificationResult.checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, result)`, it seems that the callback server which gets started by pydeequ does not get terminated automatically.

If I run code containing pydeequ on an EMR cluster for example, the port `25334` seems to stay open after the spark application closes, unless I explicitly create a `JavaGateway` with the spark session, and call the `close()` method.

```
from pydeequ.verification import *

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .config("spark.jars.packages", pydeequ.deequ_maven_coord)
    .config("spark.jars.excludes", pydeequ.f2j_maven_coord)
    .getOrCreate())


df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
            Row(a="foo", b=1, c=5),
            Row(a="bar", b=2, c=6),
            Row(a="baz", b=None, c=None)]).toDF()

from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway

check = Check(spark, CheckLevel.Warning, "Review Check")

checkResult = VerificationSuite(spark) \
    .onData(df) \
    .addCheck(
        check.hasSize(lambda x: x < 3) \
        .hasMin("b", lambda x: x == 0) \
        .isComplete("c")  \
        .isUnique("a")  \
        .isContainedIn("a", ["foo", "bar", "baz"]) \
        .isNonNegative("b")) \
    .run()

checkResult_df = VerificationResult.checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, checkResult)
checkResult_df.show(truncate=False)

a = JavaGateway(spark.sparkContext._gateway)
a.close()
```

If I don't implement the last 2 lines of code, the callback server stays open on the port.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

PyDeequ github says to use these to shutdown Spark session:

```
spark.sparkContext._gateway.shutdown_callback_server()
spark.stop()
```

Comment: tried this, and still face the same errors